Getting SignalRHub Error when calling Load Balancer "'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."
I've moved onto a project involving AngularJS version 1.8.2 along with SignlRHub version 2.4.3 that runs on an .NET server. We have migrated from HTTP to HTTPS in our application, however in one of our environments we have two servers (from my understanding). One is defined as normal HTTP, while the other is a HTTPS load balancer. Since HTTP is not secure, we must negotiate with our SignlRHub that is on our load balancer server.
We are getting this error:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at
'https://stglb.bo.lda.com/UsersHub/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&AppSourceID=240&connectionData=%5Bname%22userhub%22&_=1713'
from origin 'https://stg.fa.lda.com' has been blocked by CORS policy:
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
resource.

When we reach out to a normal HTTPS server though on a different environment, our application successfully negotiates. I've looked around to see of anyone who has dealt with the same issue, but a lot of them involve IConfigureServices which our application does not have, and usually they never mention dealing with Load Balancing. Here is my configuration for it:
public class Startup
{
  public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
  {
    var idProvider = new CustomUserIdProvider();

    GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(IUserIdProvider), () => idProvider);

    // Branch the pipeline here for requests that start with "/signalr"
    app.Map("/signalr", map =>
    {
        // Setup the CORS middleware to run before SignalR.
        // By default this will allow all origins. You can
        // configure the set of origins and/or http verbs by
        // providing a cors options with a different policy.
        map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
        {
            // You can enable JSONP by uncommenting line below.
            // JSONP requests are insecure but some older browsers (and some
            // versions of IE) require JSONP to work cross domain
            // EnableJSONP = true
        };
        // Run the SignalR pipeline. We're not using MapSignalR
        // since this branch already runs under the "/signalr"
        // path.
        map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
    });
   }
 }

We configure our WebApi here:
 public static class WebApiConfig
  {
   public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
    // Web API configuration and services

    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
  }
}

The CORS are enabled for any origin, but I don't know where else to go with this. I've referred to this: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/4457 but it doesn't seem to be compatible with my framework or the issue I'm facing. Is there a certain configuration I'm supposed to have for Load Balancers? Thanks!
